# Why is my state's value is always undefined?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I've read all the question asked that similar to my problem , but  it still cant's solve my issues . I'm fetching datas from an api and assign it's values into my state , the program compiled successfully but this message appears in the browser "TypeError: weatherData.main is undefined"

Here's my code

```
import './App.css';
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';


function App() {
  const [weatherData,setWeatherData] = useState({});
  const [position,setPosistion] = useState({});

  useEffect(()=>{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( pos => {
      setPosistion(()=>{
        return {
          latitude : pos.coords.latitude,
          longitude : pos.coords.longitude
        }
      })
    });
  },[])

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${position.latitude}&lon=${position.longitude}&units=metric&appid=a*****5`)
        .then( res => res.json() )
        .then( resJson => {
          setWeatherData(()=>resJson)
        })
  },[position]);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Weather weatherData={weatherData} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Weather = ({weatherData}) => {
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="location-time">
        <span id="location">{weatherData.name}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="weather">
        <span className="temp">{`${weatherData.main.temp} C`}</span>
        <div className="icon"></div>
        <div className="description">{weatherData.weather[0].main}</div>
        <div className="low-max">{`max : ${weatherData.main.temp_max} min : ${weatherData.main.temp_min}`}</div>
        <div className="feels-like">{`feels like : ${weatherData.main.feels_like}`}</div>
        <button >REFRESH</button>
      </div> 
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}


export default App;
```

the state contains

```
{"coord":{"lon":106.8451,"lat":-6.2146},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":302.76,"feels_like":307.06,"temp_min":300.15,"temp_max":305.93,"pressure":1007,"humidity":74},"visibility":6000,"wind":{"speed":2.57,"deg":340},"clouds":{"all":40},"dt":1613038370,"sys":{"type":1,"id":9383,"country":"ID","sunrise":1612997835,"sunset":1613042198},"timezone":25200,"id":1642911,"name":"Jakarta","cod":200}
```

Comment: Show us what `weatherData` contains

Comment: the state contains ```{"coord":{"lon":106.8451,"lat":-6.2146},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":302.76,"feels_like":307.06,"temp_min":300.15,"temp_max":305.93,"pressure":1007,"humidity":74},"visibility":6000,"wind":{"speed":2.57,"deg":340},"clouds":{"all":40},"dt":1613038370,"sys":{"type":1,"id":9383,"country":"ID","sunrise":1612997835,"sunset":1613042198},"timezone":25200,"id":1642911,"name":"Jakarta","cod":200}```

Comment: Check what Shubham explained, yiu have to do conditional rendering and show the loader initially and once the axios request is finish, show the data

Answer (score 0):

Before the data is fetched, weather is initialised to be a empty object and hence weather.main is undefined.

You should consider rendering a fallback page till weather data is fetched

```
const Weather = ({weatherData}) => {
  if(Object.keys(weatherData).length === 0) {
      return <div>{/* Somee info here or maybe a loader*/}</div>
  }
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="location-time">
        <span id="location">{weatherData.name}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="weather">
        <span className="temp">{`${weatherData.main.temp} C`}</span>
        <div className="icon"></div>
        <div className="description">{weatherData.weather[0].main}</div>
        <div className="low-max">{`max : ${weatherData.main.temp_max} min : ${weatherData.main.temp_min}`}</div>
        <div className="feels-like">{`feels like : ${weatherData.main.feels_like}`}</div>
        <button >REFRESH</button>
      </div> 
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```